# Usage of わけにはいかない

Tags: grammar

According to what I know, わけにはいかない means that someone can't do something for moral reason

> これは先生の本だから、君に貸すわけにはいかない 
>   This is my teacher's book so I can't lend it to you

But I just saw this conversation line and I can't see why they use this grammar pattern

> (situation: someone is trying to make a doctor appointment so he's talking to 受付 which I'm going to assume is the receptionist of the hospital.) 突然ですが、今日診ていただくわけにはいかないでしょうか

If I said something like

- 今日診ていただいていただけませんか

does it change the meaning or is it just a degree of politeness?

Comment: I think you want to say 今日診ていただけませんか.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> According to what I know, わけにはいかない means that someone can't do something ***for moral reason***.

That sounds rather simplistic.  「Verb + わけにはいかない」 can be used to say that one cannot do something for other reasons as well such as **laws/rules, common sense, judgement based on experience, sense of obligation**, etc.

The sentence:

> 「突然{とつぜん}ですが、今日診{きょうみ}ていただくわけにはいかないでしょうか。」

is a completely natural-sounding one that requests earnestly to see a doctor on that day (rather than on the next).  Perhaps, the speaker arrived at the hospital a little too late for outpatient reception or something.  It expresses the speaker's distress and strong desire, knowing that the receptionist could easily turn down the request.

As far as the phrase choice, this is in no way a 'normal' or 'neutral' way to make a request.  Had the speaker come to the hospital on time and/or with everything s/he needed such as a referral letter, health insurance card, etc., s/he would have ***never*** said 「突然ですが、今日診ていただくわけにはいかないでしょうか。」.

Your sentence:

「今日診ていただけませんか。」 (You used いただく twice, so I deleted one.)

does **not** imply much of the distress I discussed above.  You could use the sentence, but it will not sound nearly as desperate as the one using 「わけにはいかない」.

> does it change the meaning or is it just a degree of politeness?

It changes the meaning as explained above.  Politeness has little to nothing to do with this.  It is just how seriously and desperately you would sound regarding your desire to see a doctor.